# Hierarchy viewer is not calculating Measure, Layout, and Draw and shows not available

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm trying to run Hierarchy Viewer in Eclipse but it only shows N/A for Measure, Layout and Draw.
I have tried running Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus, and Nexus 4 emulators on both Mac and Windows using Android SDK and on a physical device Nexus S with ViewServer library but all those showed the same result as the screen shot below. Also, I tried it with a simple and complex layout. 
I was wondering how other configured the emulator to make Hierarchy Viewer fully functional. Also, is there another way to calculate the draw time for the layout?

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same problem, maybe this is a solution for you too.

If you start the hierarchyviewer, it is not measuring the times directly on start. You have to press the button named: **"Profile Node"** (The button with 3 circles) and have to wait few seconds. You can find this button in the tree view window menu. After the measuring you get the needed values.

Comment: good worked for me Note: i am using viewserver to open hierarchyviewer in real device.

Comment: What if the the measures are always green with 0.0 values? I'm testing on the emulator.

Comment: still not working for me, I tried it multiple times and waited for more rthen 2 mins precicely now.

Comment: First select on left side your wished application, relolad the view herachie, select your starting node in the view tree window. Press the three circle button.

Answer (score 3):

1. First select the node(View) for which you want to see layout times.
2. Then the three-circle icon [image]
   will be activated. Layout times will appear after you click this
   icon. It has a tool-tip `Obtain layout times for tree rooted at
   selected node`

**Note**: The layout times will be shown only for the view that you selected and all it's children views. It won't show times for its parent nodes. If you want to see layout times for all the views, select the base parent(outer most view) and then click [image].

[image]